# Doubt in the proof of Conjugacy of positive systems under reflection group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, coxeter-groups

I am stuck at a small thing in the proof of conjugacy of positive systems under a finite reflection group. I am using the notation and definitions used in the text by James E. Humphreys. I reproduce the proof below:
Theorem:Let $\Delta$ be a positive system, contained in the positive system $\Pi$. If $\alpha \in \Delta$ then $s_\alpha(\Pi \backslash {\alpha})=(\Pi \backslash  {\alpha})$

Proof: Let $\beta \in \Pi, \beta \neq \alpha$. Write $\beta =\sum_{\gamma \in \Delta}{c_\gamma \gamma}, c_\gamma \geq 0$.
$c_\gamma > 0$ for some $\gamma \neq \alpha$ (I understand why).
Now apply $s_\alpha$ to both sides: $s_\alpha \beta = \beta -c\alpha$ is a linear combination of $\Delta$ involving $\gamma$ with the same coefficient $c_\gamma$.
Because all coefficients in such an expression have like sign, $s_\alpha \beta$ must be positive.

This is the part I do not understand. Why can't it happen that $c_\alpha \neq 0$ in the expression for $\beta$ and then $c_\alpha -c \lt 0$ in the expression for $s_\alpha \beta$? Then all coefficients in the expression will not have like sign.

Comment: I do not have the book in front of me, but presumably it has already been proved that all roots are either positive or negative linear combinations of simple roots. So, since $s_\alpha \beta$ definite has at least one positive coefficient (that follows from $\beta \ne \alpha$) in its expression as a sum of elements of $\Delta$, it follows that all of the coefficients must be positive, irrespective of whether or not $c_\alpha = 0$.

Comment: @Derek Holt yes, my bad :( That all roots are linear combination of simple system with coefficients all of same sign, is what is required from the definition of a simple system. silly me:(